# For the gift to work do you need to stay there?

Tags: plot-explanation, encanto

It seems that all the Madrigal family from *Encanto* stay in the same casita and do not emigrate to other towns.

Is this because they're a closely connected family, or does the gift wear off if they go away from the candle?

Comment: There is only one village, isn't there? https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/Encanto_(location)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, we don't know. The entire film takes place in a magically charmed town surrounded on all sides by impassable mountains. Bruno, in the film's [novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/56905325), indicates that he did briefly *consider* climbing out, but that the mountains dissuaded him from doing so.

> “I don’t understand why you ‘left’ but didn’t leave?”
>
> Bruno looked down and shifted uncomfortably. “Oh, well…the mountains
> around the Encanto are pretty tall

We also see in *[The Art of Encanto](https://encanto.fandom.com/wiki/The_Art_of_Encanto)* that the valley is entirely enclosed.

> [image]

It's not clear what would happen to the family's magical powers if they left the valley. Maybe we'll find out in the sequel.